# create multiple directories using ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to create multiple directories(test1,test2) with 2 sub directories (/home/test1/bin and /home/test2/conf) similarly for test2. My playbook looks like this :

```
--
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Create directory
      file: path=/home/{{item}}/bin  state=directory
      file: path=/home/{{item}}/conf state=directory
      with_items:
          - test1
          - test2
```

However i get the following error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/ansible/lib/ansible/executor/process/worker.py", line 122, in run
    executor_result = TaskExecutor(host, task, job_vars, new_play_context, self._new_stdin, self._loader, shared_loader_obj).run()
  File "/root/ansible/lib/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 89, in run
    items = self._get_loop_items()
  File "/root/ansible/lib/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 179, in _get_loop_items
    items = self._shared_loader_obj.lookup_loader.get(self._task.loop, loader=self._loader, templar=templar).run(terms=loop_terms, variables=vars_copy)
  File "/root/ansible/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/items.py", line 26, in run
    return self._flatten(terms)
TypeError: _flatten() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "stdout": ""}
```

Whats the issue here? I'm using the latest git checkout. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: can you show the line of your code that is giving the problem? Apparently you are missing one argument to some function.

Comment: @victor I have not written any code for the above task, I'm just using the ansible modules to get it done.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that errors raised because you used `file` module 2 times in 1 task. You should only use 1 module per task.

In your case, you should use [nested loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops) to create multiple directories and subdirectories.

Example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: test
      file: path=/tmp/{{item.0}}/{{item.1}} state=directory
      with_nested:
        - ['test1', 'test2']
        - ['bin', 'conf']
```

Comment: using a single file module also gave the same error. But the nested loop code worked like a charm.Thanks!! just a quick question - can we create the same directory structure on a remote windows machine using ansible?

Comment: strangely, you can use file module twice (perhaps this is version specific?) but  `with_items` only applies to the latter for `ansible 1.9.3`

Comment: @miked I was using the latest developer version from the git source(v2.0). And for the windows machine we can use win_file module. Initially it gave me a bad response error. So i had to reboot my windows node and then it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is to create directories from a template based on a list of lists you manually create. I would suggest below is not significatly different, offers some more flexibility, and uses the newer loop keyword:

```
- file: path={{ item.path }} state={{ item.state }} owner={{ item.owner }} group={{ item.group }} mode={{ item.mode }}
  loop:
    - { "path": "/tmp/test1/bin",  "owner":  'john', "group": 'doe',   "state":  'directory', "mode":   '0775', }
    - { "path": "/tmp/test1/conf", "owner":  'john', "group": 'doe',   "state":  'directory', "mode":   '0700', }
    - { "path": "/tmp/test2/bin",  "owner":  'jane', "group": 'smith', "state":  'directory', "mode":   '0775', }
    - { "path": "/tmp/test2/conf", "owner":  'jane', "group": 'smith', "state":  'directory', "mode":   '0700', }
```

Tested on Version 2.12.7.

A more interesting idea where you seem to be going is to inner join two scalar lists and create directories from the result. I don't have an answer for that but
it would certainly scale better.